# uuencode doesn't work properly for attaching files with my below command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sunos

I am trying to `attach one file` and send few `echo messages` in the Body of an email using `mailx and uuencode`. I have below command which I have added them together, and uuencode doesn't work properly but I get echo message properly in my email.

How can I make uuencode works here? Something wrong I am doing here I guess while combing uuencode with mailx?

```
(uuencode /tmp/chart.html percentage_graph.html) | mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

But for testing purpose if I issue below command to see whether I am getting any html file or not in an attachment, then I get an email with the attachment properly.

```
(uuencode /tmp/chart.html percentage_graph.html) | mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com
```

Then what's wrong in my first command when I combine them together?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the pipeline and the heredoc both trying to send data to mailx's stdin.

Comment: So how can I add `uuencode command` such that I get both the things together?

Comment: What's this about you and @Nevzz03 asking near-identical questions all the time?  See (tangentially related, not duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944124/send-the-output-of-html-file-within-the-email-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mailx` command can get its input from the pipe (uuencode) or the heredoc (<< EOF).  But not both.

This may work for you:

```
$ mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@example.com rj@example.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2

$(uuencode /tmp/chart.html percentage_graph.html)

EOF
```

Alternately, consider using something like [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) which will let you attach files separately from the body of the message.

Comment: the heredoc feeds to the stdin of the entire pipeline (so to the stdin of uuencode, not mailx)

Comment: @ChrisDodd - yes, but that's not how the OP was using it.  `uuencode` only takes stdin if you run it with a single option, the remote filename.  The OP is taking `/tmp/chart.html`, naming it `percentage_graph.html` and trying to embed that in the body of the message a la email circa early 1990s, before MIME was invented.  His intent was to "**attach one file**".

Answer (score 0):

uuencode doesn't read stdin if you give it an input filename as you have done here.  That's because it encodes a single file.  if you want to encode two files, you need to combine them together somehow first.  You could just use `cat` if concantenating them is ok:

```
cat /tmp/chart.html - | uuencode percentage_graph.html | mailx .... << EOF
..stuff to append to chart.html
EOF
```

Comment: This uuencodes the text into the same block as the HTML file, so the resultant "attachment" will be corrupt HTML rather than text with a uuencoded HTML file embedded.  The recipient would need to uudecode the data in order to read the text of the message, which I think is not what the OP was aiming at.