# Send the output of html file within the email body

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sunos

I have an html file under `/tmp folder` as `chart.html file` which will have the output like below image when you open that `html file`

[image]

I have a shell script that I am using to send the `chart.html` file as an attachment in an email with some body message.

**Problem Statement:-**

Is is possible to send this colorful image of the html file(when you open it) within the body of an email? So that people can see this image in there email body, instead of opening the attachment file. Below is the command that I am using to send the attachment in an email with body message-

```
mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2

$(uuencode /tmp/chart.html percentage_graph.html)

EOF
```

What changes I need to make in my above command to send this colorful image within the body itself.

Comment: `uuencode` is encoding the HTML. There's nothing *interpreting* the HTML in order to include the graphic *within* the email. As you have it now, the recipient's email client *may* retrieve the graphic remotely from wherever it's hosted *if* it's publicly accessible. You will need to include MIME headers among other things if you want to include the graphic.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to include an image in the 21st century is with MIME.  Your message should basically be something like

```
From: you <you@example.net>
To: recipient <victim@example.com>
Subject: well, say something
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/related; boundary=foo

Often you have something about this being a MIME message here.

--foo
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: us-ascii

<html><yada yada><img src="cid:bar"></html>

--foo
Content-type: image/png
Content-id: bar
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

sdflkjsdflkjsdflkjsdflkjsdflksdfl=

--foo--
```

You can also try with a `text/plain` text part and a `Content-Disposition: inline` for the image; many clients will then display the image below the text.

Of course, if you already have it all in one HTML file (how? with the image?) then just attaching that with a modern MUA like `mutt` should all be doable with a simple command line.